# Investigating Random Crashes/Reboots - RaspberryPi 3B

Tags: raspbian-buster, troubleshooting, crash, reboot

We have a Raspberry Pi 3B running a custom Buster image ([PiSignage](https://github.com/colloqi/piSignage) 3.2.0 - Its for digital signage). I have recently noticed that the Pi has been crashing periodically and my troubleshooting knowledge of Linux isn't sufficient enough to figure out the root cause. I'm actually not entirely sure if the system is crashing or rebooting (by watchdog or someother service).

The Pi sits behind a TV and displays content from a webpage all day. Thats it. PiSignage (a node based app) uses chromium to do that.

I've combed through `/var/logs/`, but nothing really stands out to me aside from seeing this in dmseg `EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem`. My first guess is that I'm dealing with some file corruption or a bad SD card. Another thing to note is that the power supply is 5V-2A not 5V-2.5A. I suppose that could be part of my issue as well.

I'll post some log info below surrounding the last known crash/reboot - I was booted from SSH around 09:07. I'd love to know more about where and what to look for to troubleshoot this kind of thing. Any help is much appreciated.

**/var/log/message**

https://gist.github.com/rmscode/052ee1e677414bb139c900a4cd115485

**/var/log/syslog**

https://gist.github.com/rmscode/5221284fd31e44fc5e9ca98870d4a05e

Comment: Update: Okay, so I learned about `vcgencmd get_throttled` and that spits out `throttled=0x20000`. From my research, that means that the CPU is or has previously been capped. Would be the result of a heat issue? I just checked the Pi and it is a little toasty at 74.6'C. I pulled the cover off (official raspbery pi case) and the temp dropped by 4 degrees.

Comment: Just restore your backup to a new SD Card.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out. There is a specific webpage that makes chromium cook the cpu when display via PiSignage. It pegs the CPU at 100% and the Pi eventually crashes. Thanks for always being around to offer your advice @Milliways. I see you around here all the time.

Comment: if it's not a private webpage, then please share the URL

Comment: You're right, I should have added some more information. I can't share the webpage, but I can tell you that the culprit was a weather widget embedded in the page - https://weatherwidget.io. Turning off the animated weather icons drastically reduced the amount of CPU chromium used.